# Connecting to Jenkins command line using Github authentication

Tags: jenkins

How can I connect to the Jenkins command line, when the server is using Github authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Jenkins command line username/password options are completely broken. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/8PxjeqhgzHs
However, it's possible to connect using SSH keys.